# C++ Function Pointer as Argument and Classes?

Tags: c++

Hmm I'm reading some guides on this but I can't figure this out, how do I properly use function pointers in C++?

I have a class that I want to call a function after it has finished whatever it is doing at the moment, like this:

```
class WindowImages
{
    public:
        void Update()
        {
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _images.size(); i++)
            {
                //Do something
                _images[i]->MyFunctionPointer();
            }
        }
        void Add(Image* image, void (*func)(void))
        {
            image->function = func; //this is wrong
            _images.push_back(image);
        }         

    private:
        vector<Image*> _images;
}

class Image
{
    public:
        void ImageClicked();

        void *function(void);
};

void main()
{
    Image* image = new Image();

    WindowImages images;
    images.Add(image, image->ImageClicked);
}
```

I'm trying to add the image to the vector, and pass a function as argument that will be called when the images class finish doing whatever it has to do with each image.
The functions will be different per image but they'll all be in the **void function()** format.

I've been trying a bunch of things but got nothing so far, how can I do this?
Also, if you happen to have a more... beginner friendly tutorial or guide on function pointers (and even maybe C++ 11 lambdas) that'd be really helpful!

Comment: You can use an `std::function` instead of a function pointer.

Comment: don't forget to call `delete` on your `Image` object :)

Comment: I believe that void *function(void); declares a function named 'function' that takes void and returns a void *. It is not a function pointer.

Comment: This on [member function pointers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) may be of interest.

Comment: You want `void (*function)(void);` declares a function pointer. But *member function pointers* are different beasts.

Comment: The declaration syntax is `void (*funcp)(void);`, which declares `funcp` as a pointer to a function which takes no arguments and returns no result.

Comment: @YoungJohn You're right, I forgot about the parenthesis, but still it seems the Class "Image" is messing it up... the error is that the expected argument is of the type "void function()", not "void Image::function()"

Comment: Remember that ImageClicked as a member function does not take void, it actually has an implicit parameter representing 'this'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this pointer and member function address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669182/this-pointer-and-member-function-address)

Comment: Why are you trying to use a (member) function pointer here when you already have the object and can just call the function you want directly?

Comment: @ZacHowland Because the WindowImages are going to do a bunch of checks and tests, and I want to specify certain function when each or certain conditions are met. In the example, I want to add a "collision" code, so when that happens, I want to call the "collisionFunction". Depending on the condition I'd call a different function.

Comment: @Danicco It sounds like you would be better served by making the various functions you want (e.g. "HandleCollision()`) as virtual member functions and override them appropriately - then your collision code in `WindowImages` would simply call `HandleCollision()` when one occurs on a given image.  It sounds like you are over-engineering this.

Comment: @Danicco What's `Image` BTW?? I get a compilation error (`prog.cpp:16: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Image'`) checking your [sample](http://ideone.com/bTHXRE) ...

Comment: @ZacHowland I've thought of other possibilities, but I can't really do that, this is the code I'm making for a game engine and this is the interface I'm leaving open for programmers. So I'd like that a game programmer could create his own function (or not), and when certain conditions are met (collisions, out of screen, among others) it'd call the function he specifies. For example, if he doesn't want any function to be called when the object is out of screen, nothing happens, but for another object he might want to, so I want to call that function when my engine detects the condition.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you copy/pasted it could be because I forgot the ; in the class WindowImages.

Comment: @Dannico if you are using C++11 you should definitely use std::function like Malloc says. Here is a link to a blog that describes the usage of std::function.
http://oopscenities.net/2012/02/24/c11-stdfunction-and-stdbind/

Comment: @Danicco That is exactly *why* virtual functions would serve you better.  It will give you an API that is easier to understand and implement, and will make your life (as the API designer) much easier.

Comment: @Danicco [That doesn't fix it ...](http://ideone.com/bTHXRE) :(

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ First time using this site, hope it works (since it wouldn't compile with the errors, I commented them): http://ideone.com/cpP2NV

Comment: @Danicco Fork the sample I gave, and try to get it compile clean there, or be more specific about the particular environment you are using and why you expect a different behavior of your actually used toolchain.

Comment: @Danicco Taking your example, [this](http://ideone.com/mqEVVc) is what it could look like just using virtual functions.  Using pointers to member functions is going to make your API a pain to use (you are basically re-inventing virtual functions).

Comment: @ZacHowland Make [this](http://ideone.com/mqEVVc) an answer, it suffices very well (despite the OP insists to use function pointers to solve the problem)! Vtable mechanisms effectively already do provide the wanted fn pointers and resolution what to call!!

Comment: @ZacHowland Thanks for the help but I've tried that before. I really simplified the problem so I could post here without being a huge text/code block, but [this code](http://ideone.com/NXbuBm) would be my real problem. I commented on what it is and what I want to do. By adding an interface I'd be limiting the classes and forcing all classes the programmer creates to implement them, and that's not what I want, I want to let them handle only the events/conditions they want to (check the code comments for details).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Check the above comment, I don't know how to reply to multiple users in the same comment =/

Comment: @Danicco THX for the extra notification (I'm facing that stupid double address restriction often, and feel annoyed also! But it simply forces you, to address comments one by one (which isn't a such bad concept)) As for your comments and completed sample, I still stick to join Zac's proposal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using a regular function pointer for your callback. You're using a non-static *member* function pointer, so the regular function pointer syntax and calling mechanics aren't going to work. There is a significant difference both in the pointer declaration syntax and the mechanism used for invoking non-static members.

To declare a pointer-to-member function for a member of the `Image` class taking no parameters and returning `void`, the syntax would be:

```
void (Image::*function)().
```

Invoking a member function is done using one of two special operators, `->*` when using an object pointer, or `.*` when using an object reference. For example:

```
// declare a pointer to Image member function
void (Image::*function)();

// assign address of member function
function = &Image::ImageClicked;

// uses ->* for access
Image *pObj = new Image();
(pObj->*function)();

// uses .* for access
Image image;
(image.*function)();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Pretty close until the last part, which should be `(_images[i]->*function)()` Apart from that it looks good. Hope that phone call went well. And note to the OP, this carries through on virtual functions as well. [See it live](http://ideone.com/HHkuk5)

Comment: @manpat Would you like to improve formatting and give code samples (referring to what the OP gave) with your answer please?

Comment: I'll add a proper code block when i'm next on my laptop. I'm actually moving at the moment so it might be a couple of hours

Comment: @Manpat taken care of. hope its ok with you.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah that's fine. Thanks for that.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Manpat: This, plus templates, worked! Also really thanks for explaining why it wasn't working before (calling a non-static function, although you edited it out) that made a lot of sense and made me understand these function pointers much better!

Comment: @Danicco glad it worked. editing out anything bringing clarity to the failure prior was not intentional, so sorry for that. But very glad you get why non-static members need a `this` and an operator to allow its dispatch into the member function. That said, I *strongly* suggest heeding the advice of many in this question and consider using virtual function dispatching instead. it is far more flexible. Generally you don't bite off member-function pointers without a *very* specific reason to do so, so give that consideration.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think your intention is better done via C++ polymorphism, though which is done by `function pointer` underhood. [C++ function pointer](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) tutorial
The following code does what you want to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void f1() {
    cout << "f1()" << endl;
}
void f2() {
    cout << "f2()" << endl;
}
void f3() {
    cout << "f3()" << endl;
}    
class A {
public:
    void (*fp)();
};

class B {
public:
    void add(A* a, void (*fp)()) {
        a->fp = fp;
        vec_a.push_back(a);
    }
    ~B() {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec_a.size(); ++i) {
            vec_a[i]->fp();
        }
    }
private:
    vector<A*> vec_a;
};

int main() {
    B *b = new B();
    A* a[3];
    a[0] = new A();
    a[1] = new A();
    a[2] = new A();
    b->add(a[0], f1);
    b->add(a[1], f2);
    b->add(a[2], f3);
    delete b;
}
```

The output is

```
f1()
f2()
f3()
```

Answer (score -2):

First and foremost, I suggest against using function pointers in C++.  In general, the same functionality can and should be achieved using virtual classes.

When working with function pointers, I find typedefs to be really useful to keep things organized.  This somewhat contrived example accomplishes roughly what you are trying to do...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

typedef void (*fptr_type) (int);

void printSquare (int i) {
   printf ("%d\n", i * i);
   return;
}

void printDouble (int i) {
   printf ("%d\n", 2 * i);
   return;
}

class IntFPtrClass {
   public:
      int intVal;
      fptr_type fptr;

      IntFPtrClass (int i, fptr_type f) : intVal(i), fptr(f) { }

   // Just to show that static methods can be used as function pointers.
   static void printPlusOne(int i) {
      printf ("%d\n", i + 1);
      return;
   }
};

int main (void)
{
   std::vector<IntFPtrClass> my_vector;

   my_vector.push_back (IntFPtrClass(3, printSquare));
   my_vector.push_back (IntFPtrClass(5, printDouble));
   my_vector.push_back (IntFPtrClass(7, IntFPtrClass::printPlusOne));

   for (int i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); ++i)
   {
      my_vector[i].fptr(my_vector[i].intVal);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 _'I suggest against using function pointers in C++. In genera'_ **NO!** I can't really foster that statement at all! That's just narrowing too much about all the aspects ...